# Notifying other page database item has changed, best practice for MVVM WP7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

First of all, I'm using MVVM for this and I would like to continue using it and ofc using the best practices as well.

I have a Mainpage which will display a list of items. On another page you can add such items. The items will be saved in a database which came with the Mango update.

When a item is added I want to navigate back to the mainpage and I want the list to be updated automatically. Is this possible and what's the best way? I'm thinking of following scenario's:

- Use the Refresh query string when you navigate. Check in the back end of your main if there is a refresh. Then send a message 2 the ViewModel that he needs to update his list. I have tried this and this works. But this doesn't really sound the right way for MVVM.
- Can't this be done with the NotifyPropertyChanged event that you can raise on your Database Model ? Or doesn't it work over different pages?
- Reload the whole ViewModel for the main page somehow.

Any other idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MVVM-Lights Messenger.  The MainViewMode can subscribe to a Refresh event and the ViewModel where the items are added can publish a Refresh event.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionSilverlightPt2.aspx#Messenger) is a good example of how messenger can be used.

Comment: Sounds logical but can't you just send the newly added object to the MainViewModel then and add it 2 the collection to save a database round trip? Or isn't this advised?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I suppose you could pass it back and then insert it but is it a concern of the MainPageViewModel?  This is one reason I like Caliburn Micro, each ViewModel has a life-cycle.  So, OnActivate, reload the list.  MVVM-Light might have something like this no as well.

Comment: I'll check Caliburn Micro out, looks promising. Thanks !